# Unknown xx req signal for NoC coding

Tags: verilog, fpga

I am having unknown xx for ***req[1:0]*** signal in a [NoC verilog code implementation](https://gist.github.com/promach/cf3ae626a85badad6cd822d3107c86b7#file-spidergon_router-v-L337-L375)

Please advise.

[image: unknown xx signal]

Comment: What about `vc_is_to_be_allocated`, `port_num`,  `vc_num`, and  `input_flit_type`? Are these signals defined when `req` goes undefined?

Comment: there could be a multitude of reasons. It is impossible to draw any conclusion from the images you provided. you need to debug it. And do not post images for the code.

Comment: "Please advise." A picture doesn't provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

https://gist.github.com/promach/cf3ae626a85badad6cd822d3107c86b7/revisions#diff-7d0a6c3024f080f56a53770135bf21ab

Just change

```
(.clk(clk), .reset(reset), .req(req[granted_port]), .grant(granted_vc));
```

to

```
(.clk(clk), .reset(reset), .req(req[granted_port_index]), .grant(granted_vc));
```